# Close a Workbook if opened

Tags: excel, vba

I would like an error handler to handle closing an Excel workbook that is not open.

I tried below code.

```
If Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").IsOpen Then 
     Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False 
Else: Resume Next 
MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical 
End If
```

This gives me an error message:

> Run time Error: 9 Subscript Out of Range.

Comment: Questions without code tend to get closed here.  What code did you try, and what problems did you run into?

Comment: I tried using below code recently.

   If Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").IsOpen Then

    Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False

    Else: Resume Next

    
    MsgBox "Error: (" & Err.Number & ") " & Err.Description, vbCritical

    End If

This gives me an Error message: Run time Error: 9
Subscript Out of Range.

Am very new to VBA & not sure whether I've used the correct statement nor cant understand whats going wrong.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

All you really need is

```
On Error Resume Next
Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").Close SaveChanges:=False
On Error Goto 0
```

You can ignore the error if there is no workbook open with that name.

Comment: Thanks Tim, Tried using the code, but encountered same Error Message: Subscript out of Range & while I Debug it highlight below code:----
If Workbooks("Combo.xlsx").IsOpen Then -----

Looks like it's giving an Error If the Workbook id Not opened. I want to skip these codes if the file is already opened & go to next steps without giving an Error Message.
Thanks.

Comment: What is your setting in the VB editor under *Tools>Options>General>Error trapping* ?  Make sure it's not "Break on all errors" or the On Error Resume Next can't do its job here.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem that the On Error Resume Next didn't seem to work for this. My settings are only to break on unhandled errors so I can't understand why it keeps breaking when trying to close.

Anyway, I made this simple workaround subroutine to call when closing the workbook:

```
Private Sub closeWorkbookIfOpen(wb As Workbook)
    On Error GoTo NotOpen

    wb.Close

NotOpen:
End Sub
```

Not sure why the Resume Next doesn't work, but this seems to do the trick!